# Updating one-to-many reference field in Django also updates other objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have an existing DB with two tables, called Identities and Accounts, which I'm trying to manage using Django ORM.

Identities has a one-to-many relationship with Accounts, and I modeled the two tables like this:

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "Identities"
    i_id = models.AutoField(db_column = "I_ID", primary_key = True) 
    name = models.CharField(db_column = "DisplayName", max_length = 200)

class Account(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "Accounts"
    name = models.CharField(db_column = "Name", max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    identity = models.ForeignKey("Identity", db_column = "I_ID", blank = True, null = True, related_name = "accounts")
```

My problem is that when I update the identity associated to an account, all accounts associated to the new identity will switch to the new one:

```
old_identity = Identity.objects.create(name = "Old")
new_identity = Identity.objects.create(name = "New")
account_1 = Account.objects.create(name = "account_1", identity = old_identity)
account_2 = Account.objects.create(name = "account_2", identity = old_identity)

# change the identity for account_1:
account_1.identity = new_identity
account_1.save()

# read account_2 from DB and check identity
account_2 = Account.objects.get(name = "account_2")

# identity is now "New" also for account_2!
print account_2.identity.name
```

If I do the same update directly in the DB, only the account I change has the identity changed, and not all the accounts associated to the identity, so this is something introduced by Django.

What should I do to have only one account updated when I change the `identity` field?

**NOTE**: just to be clear, both references are changed in the database as well, this is not a problem of data not being refreshed or something like that.

Comment: @danihp: changed the code according to your suggestion, thanks. The results are the same, of course.

Comment: Is this the full code for both models? Do you have any custom managers, or any other methods defined?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the models have some more fieds (email, domain...) but the relevant bits are there. I have no custom managers. There are some methods defined on the classes, but the problem occurs even if I do not invoke them. I think this could have something to do with the definition of the relationship...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check problem out of published relevant code. Posted code runs as expected:

Creating tables:

```
(venv)dani@egg-v3:~/tmp/lldldl/paolo$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: mytest
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table mytest_identity
    Creating table mytest_account
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Running:

```
(venv)dani@egg-v3:~/tmp/lldldl/paolo$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mytest.models import Account,Identity
>>> old_identity = Identity.objects.create(name = "Old")
>>> new_identity = Identity.objects.create(name = "New")
>>> account_1 = Account.objects.create(name = "account_1", 
                                       identity = old_identity)
>>> account_2 = Account.objects.create(name = "account_2", 
                                       identity = old_identity)
>>> 
>>> # change the identity for account_1:
>>> account_1.identity = new_identity
>>> account_1.save()
>>> 
>>> # read account_2 from DB and check identity
>>> account_2 = Account.objects.get(name = "account_2")
>>> 
>>> # identity is now "New" also for account_2!
>>> print account_2.identity.name 
Old
>>>
```

Tested with django 1.7 and sqlite3. Perhaps some database triggers? Post/Pre save signals?

Comment: Could you print all the primary keys in between statements please.

Comment: of course, change your code in answer and I will copy it in my shell. Send me a comment when all be ready.

Comment: @danihp: thanks for taking the time to test this - in the end it was a double primary key defined on one of the tables that caused the problem...